# Redactor - formattingAdd isn't changing code

Tags: craft3, redactor

I added a custom formattingAdd to my Standard.json file in my Redactor config. It's supposed to add the attribute `data-aos="fade-right"` to a paragraph tag. The "Animate" format option is showing up in the CP, but when I select that format the code doesn't change (it stays just a normal `p` without the `data-aos="fade-right` attribute).

```
{
"buttons": ["html", "formatting", "bold", "italic", "unorderedlist", "orderedlist", "link"],
  "plugins": ["fullscreen", "video"],
  "linkNewTab": true,
  "toolbarFixed": true,
  "formatting" : ["animate", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "p"],
  "formattingAdd": {
    "animate": {
      "title": "Animate",
      "args": ["p", "data-aos", "fade-right", "toggle"]
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried this with classes as well, like this:

```
"formattingAdd": {
  "note": {
    "title": "Note",
    "args": ["p", "class", "note"]
  }
}
```

but the `note` class isn't added to the `p` tags either.

Any ideas why the attribute and class aren't showing up in the `p` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for data attributes:

```
"formattingAdd": {
    "add-animate": {
        "title": "Animate",
        "api": "module.block.format",
        "args": {
            "tag": "p",
            "attr": {
                "data-aos": "fade-right"
            },
            "type": "toggle"
        }
    }
}
```

This for classes:

```
"formattingAdd": {
    "add-note": {
        "title": "Note",
        "api": "module.block.format",
        "args": {
            "tag": "p",
            "class": "note"
        }
    }
}
```

[redactor settings formatting](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/formatting/#s-formattingadd)